# Reinforcement learning algorithms dependency on the initial state

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I would like to know whether in learning algorithms, convergence to the optimum depends on the initial parameters. I mean can you reach the optimum if you start from a given initial state, but you might miss this optimum if you start from another one?

Comment: Can you please give more details on the particular application you are looking for & any specific algorithms you have in mind?

Comment: +1 to @Nishad, at present this is impossibly vague. Convergence proofs can rely on different assumptions. E.g. q-learning converges assuming each state is visited infinitely often.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the learning algorithm. Many TD learning algorithms are guaranteed to converge to the optimum policy irrespective of the initial parameters, provided some assumptions, such as being able to visit each state an unlimited number of times.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your objective function. If your objective function is convex, then irrespective of the starting point, there is a high likelihood of reaching the optimum, assuming you've set the other parameters right - such as the step size and the number of iterations or you have enough data.

If your objective is non convex with multiple maxima, different starting points may lead to different solutions.